# TreeView in extjs 4 as editor

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Can I use a treeview or treepanel in an extjs 4 panel as an editor for a column? If yes, how?
A js fiddle would be much appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basicly what you need is to extend base Picker class.
There's allready an existing implementation of treepicker. Check it out first http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198856-Ext.ux.TreeCombo

Comment: It solved the problem, but it has buggy behaviour. are you the author? Every time I try to make a selection, the first option is selected

Comment: no, i'm not an author. In my company we had a similar problem so one of my co-wokers implemented a custom picker. If you want to keep it simple - use celledit and a modal window with a tree instead of picker